# momentjs parseZone function weird behaviour when date-time string contains UTC offset +00:00

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am seeing a weird behaviour with momentjs `parseZone` function when using it to parse a date-time string containing UTC offset `+00:00`. The issue is mentioned as comments in the code snippet below:

```js
var a1 = 'Jan 24, 2024 12:43 +00:00';
var a = moment.parseZone(a1, 'MMM DD, YYYY  hh:mm A Z');
console.log(">>>> a: " + a.format()); 
// outputs unexpected 2024-01-23T18:30:00Z

var b1 = 'Jan 24, 2024 12:43';
var b = moment.parseZone(b1, 'MMM DD, YYYY  hh:mm A');
console.log(">>>> b: " + b.format()); 
// outputs expected 2024-01-24T12:43:00Z

var c1 = "Jan 24, 2024  10:54 +00:00";
var c = moment.parseZone(c1, 'MMM DD, YYYY  hh:mm Z')
console.log(">>>> c: " + c.format());
// outputs expected 2024-01-24T10:54:00Z
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.30.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Can anybody please explain why `a` holds unexpected result but `b` and `c` expected result?

Thanks.

**=========== Update**

Based on the comments rectifying the following parts in the code-snippet above resolves the issue

```
var a1 = 'Jan 24, 2024 12:43 PM +00:00'; // added PM
var a = moment.parseZone(a1, 'MMM DD, YYYY hh:mm A Z'); // removed one space before `hh`

var b = moment.parseZone(b1, 'MMM DD, YYYY hh:mm'); // removed one space before `hh`

var c = moment.parseZone(c1, 'MMM DD, YYYY hh:mm Z') // removed one space before `hh`
```

Comment: `YYYY  hh:mm` - why do you have _two_ space characters between those parts, when your input values only have one? Getting `a: 2024-01-24T12:43:00Z`, as soon as I fix that.

Comment: @CBroe I see the same thing, but I can't explain it; the other formats also have the extra space.

Comment: why do you add `A` or `Z` at the end? I never used them, and without them it works correctly. What should they do?

Comment: `var a1 = 'Jan 24, 2024 12:43 +00:00';` doesn't include an am/pm indicator. Why include `A` in the format string? Neither does `var b1 = 'Jan 24, 2024 12:43';`! The format string should match the format of the string being parsed!

Comment: Thanks all. I have edited my post by adding an update. But regarding the extra space before `hh` I do think momentjs should be bit lenient.

Comment: @JigneshGohel I agree, however nobody is going to be fixing moment.js now.

Comment: @JigneshGohel …or at least I would expect it to throw an error (or return `null` or whatever) if the input string does not comply with the format